# In which episode did Luffy say the following quote?

Tags: one-piece

I want to know in which episode Luffy said the following quote:

> You came without fear. Don't have any regrets, no matter what happens.
>   This is the duel you wanted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's from **Episode 236**: [this](https://youtu.be/j0BtHTmDfAc?t=3m29s) is a clip from the episode at the scene you mentioned.

The context is the duel between Usopp and Luffy: after Luffy decided to buy a new ship and abandon the Going Merry, Usopp abandons the crew and challenged Luffy to a duel. The cross talk is between the two of them just before the duel began.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 3):

While I don't have a specific episode number, I've found some context that can help you find it:

http://tieba.baidu.com/p/445238214

It sounds like this happened around the beginning of the Water 7 arc, which is around the time where the Going Merry had damage to it's keel and couldn't be fixed, and Usopp and Luffy get into a fight about it.

Comment: mmm it seems to me it was when the two giants Dorry and Brogy fought, since he talk about duel. but of course i'm not sure

Comment: finally you're right :)